# Redirecting a page automatically in PHP

Tags: php, html, http

I want to redirect a page automatically in PHP

Logout.php:

```
<?php 
  include "base.php"; 
  $_SESSION = array(); session_destroy();
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="=0;URL=index.php" />
```

Where base.php calls the database and starts the session:

```
<?php
  session_start();  
  $dbhost = "localhost";
  $dbname = "login";
  $dbuser = "root";
  $dbpass = "";
  mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());  
  mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());  
?>
```

When pressing logout, I am not getting back to `index.php`.

Comment: [**Heads up about the `mysql_*` functions**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work, you had an extra `=` before `0`:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=index.php" />
```

Linky https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Answer (score 34):

As far as I know, `HTML`, `JavaScript` and `PHP` provide their own way of page / header redirection. Here are three examples, showing how to redirect to `http://google.com`

#### # `JavaScript:`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://google.com";
</script>
```

#### # `HTML:`

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://google.com'"/>
```

> <kbd>Note</kbd> The 0 in `content="0;`, is a value for seconds. It tells the browser how many seconds it should wait before starting the redirect.

#### # `PHP:`

```
<?php

header('Location: http://www.google.com');
```

> <kbd>Note</kbd> A PHP [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) must be *Always* be placed before outputting anything to the browser; even a single empty space. Otherwise, it will cause the infamous "[header already sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)" errors.

Answer (score 7):

you can put this on your PHP code:

```
header('Location:index.php');
```

Note that as per all [headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), this must be placed before any output (even whitespace).

Comment: i was going to write but who is first, always a winner!

Comment: glad you mentioned the fact regarding output before headers

Comment: Should be an full (a.k.a. absolute) URL according to the HTTP spec.

Comment: @gamehelp16 - Actually it is advised to use absolute URL's when using the redirect(); function instead of relative URL's

Comment: I dint get the part **must be placed before any output (even whitespace)**

Answer (score 3):

Meta refresh syntax is slightly wrong

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/index.php'">
```

More details here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

The cleaner way is to send a http redirect header

More details here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

logout.php

```
<?php
..
session_destroy();
header( 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header( 'Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . '/index.php' );
exit(0);
```

Concerning absolute URIs in redirects W3C says

14.30 Location

> The Location response-header field is used to redirect the recipient to a location other than the Request-URI for completion of the request or identification of a new resource. For 201 (Created) responses, the Location is that of the new resource which was created by the request. For 3xx responses, the location SHOULD indicate the server's preferred URI for automatic redirection to the resource. The field value consists of a single absolute URI.
>
> ```
>    Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI
> ```
>
> An example is:
>
> ```
>    Location: http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/People.html
> ```

Source: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: Agreed meta not a good approach for redirection, by the way in your point of view (OFF TOPIC) is it good to stop caching the content with meta tags or it should be good with another approach?

Comment: @soft genic I prefer headers because this can be read in HEAD requests and by servers like a proxy, not just by the retrieving  browser. Also the overhead is slightly bigger which doesn't really make a difference tho (HTML can be gzip compressed, headers can't)

Comment: @Pee Haa, thanks for the reminder. I've modified the code above

Answer (score 1):

In the case you need to redirect the web page with a PHP variable include you can do this: where `$user[0]` is PHP variable. In that way, the next web page `user.php` can get the value of the variable.

```
header('Location:./user.php?u_id='.$user[0]);
```

or

```
header("Location:./user.php?u_id=$user[0]");
```